# Unique web site administration tool

Tags: asp.net, membership, wsat

i'd like to create a Unique Web Site Administration Tool (UWSAT) to admin all users for all my websites on production server.

Basically the idea is to have the UWSAT with only an admin user; when the admin log the tool he could navigate the applications, select one and see its users . He could add new user to an existing application, or create a user specifying a new application name (as far as i know that create the application too).

The problem i'm facing is that to add a user to an application i have to set the Membership.ApplicationName but i read this should be avoided.

So i ask you : should i create a different MembershipProvider for each application and call it when i have to manage users for that application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a role, and assigning it to the users. The role would be the application they should have access to.

The [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) is one way to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure i undestand what you mean. Each users as its own role within each application. Now i have an admin section on each website, but is essentially the same for each one; i just want to "centralize" all these admin sections creating a unique administration tool.

Comment: No one has faced the same problem?